# Searching in Xcode not finding results (searching my source)

Tags: xcode, search

I'm pulling my hair out on this and Google results are skewed since it thinks I want to find out how to code something.

My problem is that when trying to search my code with the String Matching box it finds nothing, even if I enter something that is on the screen below.

Is it Spotlight that is delivering these results? I'm not excluding anything in my Spotlight index so should I just rebuild the index?

Comment: This turned out to be a really stupid question (yes, they do exist). Some how I got into my head that the search box in the upper right corner of Xcode would search across all of your project code. As it turns out this box is for filtering the file list. Full project code search is found under the Edit menu.

Answer (score 41):

At the top of the Xcode search field, you probably want to select:

```
Find > Text > Containing
```

rather than any of:

```
Find > Text > Matching
Find > References > Matching
Find > References > Containing
```

I did not (knowingly) switch this to "Text Matching" or "References", but there it was set. "Text Containing" is a more useful search type for most searches.

Comment: Note the "find > TEXT > Matching" too, mine had changed to "find > REFERENCES > Matching" which finds some things depending on what you are looking for.

Comment: Still relevant in September 2021! This helped me in Xcode 12.5 which at some point (and for reasons unknown to me) switching to Find > References > Containing.

Answer (score 34):

This happens to me after doing this: from editor, select a word, then right-click on it, then choose "Find Selected Symbol in Workspace".

As a consequence, the finder automatically sets itself to:

```
Find > Reference > Containing
```

To search for a given text, you have to re-set it to:

```
Find > Text > Containing
```

Comment: I was having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes this happens to me when the `"In Selected Items"` is selected in the combobox on the right side of the search string.

If this selected, you only get a search in whatever files are selected in your project window.  Change it to `"In Project"` to search all your source files.

Note that the files need to be inside of your current Xcode project (just opening them from the finder won't add them.)  You may also be interested in the `"In Open Files"` option, which is faster for large projects.

Answer (score 3):

I got stuck on this one because I didn't realize that I had to hit `RETURN` to see the results :P. Normally the results changes dynamically as you write, but Xcode 11 isn't apparently there yet.

Answer (score 2):

Even with all filters disabled as described in previous answers, Xcode still doesn't always find all occurrences of a string in some of my projects, even though these occurrences are reached just fine when choosing Jump to Definition.

To do a literal full text search (note, this is much slower than the pre-indexed search), you can create a Search Scope that just searches the full project folder, by adding a Folder location in the Scope editor:

[image]