# Xcode search not working properly

Tags: xcode

I've been having trouble with the search (Command+Shift+F) function in in Xcode. I searched through the internet but didn't seem to find a solution. Seems to be failing only on a specific project (the other projects I work seem to be fine), and I use the 'search' option very often.

I's there some kind of "cache" for the Xcode search? And is there a way to reset that? Any ideas?

[image]

Here I am searching a string I've taken out from the project! So I am positive it should return a location inside my project.

Comment: Your post title says "Xcode search now working properly" did you mean "**not** working properly"?

Comment: looks like there is an extra space between the title and { in your code. Are you sure they both are exactly same ?

Comment: find>text>containing  see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838817/searching-in-xcode-not-finding-results-searching-my-source

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I copied the search from the code, so it's exactly the same.

Comment: @WilsonXJ tried that but didn't do the trick

Comment: @IgnacioOroná but in my project : find>text>containing -> find it ,find>references>containing -> not found , everything seems fine

Comment: Agree with IgnacioOroná, find>text is the key. After changing to that you will also need to repeat the search (click in the search box and press return).

Comment: @WilsonXJ you were right! That was it finally.. Would you like to answer the question so I can mark it as answered? Txs

Comment: @IgnacioOroná i post it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching in Xcode not finding results (searching my source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838817/searching-in-xcode-not-finding-results-searching-my-source)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want to search for text in the project, you should change the search parameters to:

`Find > Text > Containing`

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You may have multiple lines in the search field which you cannot see.

Try pressing Cmd-A then Backspace in the search box to fully clear it.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this issue (which is how I found this post). In my case, everything was set as it should be:

1. Find
2. Text
3. Containing
4. Ignoring Case

and it still would not find text.

It appeared to be in my case, a corrupted index. I Quit Xcode and deleted all derived data using DevCleaner from the App Store (not affiliated, but easier than doing it manually).

After that, I relaunched Xcode, waited a couple of minutes for the indexes to rebuild and everything works fine again.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my issue as well! For anyone else with this problem recently - I think my index got corrupted due to the Dropbox [online files issue](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/macos-12-monterey-support) in Monterey.

Comment: Cleaning derived data fixed my issue as well. In my case the search was not finding text inside storyboards so was hard to find to which XIB an outlet was belonging to. Thank you Matthew!

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on searchfield
2. Select `Find` above the searchfield
3. Change to `Find > Text > Containing`

then problem solved